# jdbc postgres select avg() query takes very long to execute and returns null

Tags: java, postgresql, select, jdbc, average

I'm trying to fetch the average of a column from my postgresql db using java.
Here's the query:

```
select cast(avg(qtime) as varchar) as average from es_logger where qdate >= '07-JUL-15 10:00:00' and qdate < '07-JUL-15 11:00:00' and ip = 'x.x.x.x'
```

This query executes in about 100ms in the postgresql console but takes nearly 10 seconds to execute and return when called from my java code.

Here's the code snippet:

```
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
rs.next();
String d = rs.getString(1);
```

Moreover, this query always returns `null` in java whereas it gives a proper answer in the postgresql console.

I've tried running other `select` queries from my code and they run just fine.

Can someone please help me explain why this might be happening?

Edit: I'm using Java 1.7_51 with postgresql 9.2 and driver postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar

Comment: Can you post the actual query executed on the server by JDBC.

Comment: @RomanC How can I find that?

Comment: My be if you print the statement code, that is already prepared or use some JDBC logging tools.

Comment: The query I've posted in the question is the query I get when I print the `ps` object.

Comment: How do you get connection?

Comment: `con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://myhost", user, pass);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83553/discussion-between-binoy-dalal-and-roman-c).

Comment: Why do you cast the number to a varchar? `avg()` will return null if no rows satisfy the `where` condition. What does `select count(*) from es_logger where qdate >= '07-JUL-15 10:00:00' and qdate < '07-JUL-15 11:00:00' and ip = 'x.x.x.x'` return?

Comment: `select count(*)` also returns 0 and it takes very long to return as well. On the db, I get about 1700 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got round to figuring it out.

Turns out that:

1) The long repsonse time is a database issue. The same query works pretty quick on a different postgresql database.

2) The null values were being returned because I was passing my timestamp parameter as a string. Simply passed it as a timestamp as suggested [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-insert-timestamp-value-in-preparedstatement/) and it worked.